# Retrieve sleep data for users not using GoogleFit in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-fit

I am making a react-native app where I need to retrieve user's sleep hours and send them to server. Now, I can use GoogleFit API but it only returns the results if and only if the user uses GoogleFit with the same account connected to my app. But for non GoogleFit users, how can I retrieve the sleep hours, because for them GoogleFit returns an empty array?